# How can I upload a file to a Sharepoint Document Library through SOAP web services using Java?

Tags: document, file-upload, soap

I'm trying to upload a document to a document library using the SP 2010 SOAP copy web service from Java.

Any idea how to [do this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-using-silverlight-and-cl) in Java?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
String[] destinationUrls = {mySiteUrl + "/" + listName + "/" + fileName};

// Set up the metadata
FieldInformation titleInfo = new FieldInformation();
titleInfo.setDisplayName("Title");
titleInfo.setInternalName("Title");
titleInfo.setType(FieldType.TEXT);
titleInfo.setValue("DocumentTitle");

// Content type meta
FieldInformation contentTypeInfo = new FieldInformation();
contentTypeInfo.setDisplayName("Content Type");
contentTypeInfo.setInternalName("Content Type");
contentTypeInfo.setType(FieldType.CHOICE);
contentTypeInfo.setValue("Document");

FieldInformation[] metadata = { titleInfo, contentTypeInfo };

// Copy the new file to the portal document list
Long copyIntoResult;
CopyResult[] result;

client.copyIntoItems("http://null", destinationUrls, metadata, fileBytes, copyIntoResult, result);
```

But Eclipse reports that my use of copyIntoItems "in the type CopySoap is not applicable for the arguments". Obviously, my supplied arguments are incorrect.

The WSDL-generated signature for the copyIntoItems() method looks like:

```
copyIntoItems(String, DestinationUrlCollection, FieldInformationCollection, byte[], Holder<Long>, Holder<CopyResultCollection>);
```

But those Collection types and Holder only supply protected accessors, i.e. no way to set input state.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Related question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read the generated code comments close enough. Here's the solution:

```
DestinationUrlCollection destinationUrls = new DestinationUrlCollection();
destinationUrls.getString().add(_siteUrl + listName + "/" + fileName);

// Set up the metadata
// Remark: don't set the Name field, because this is the name of the document
FieldInformation titleInfo = new FieldInformation();
// (same as before)

// Content type meta
FieldInformation contentTypeInfo = new FieldInformation();
// (same as before)

FieldInformationCollection metadata = new FieldInformationCollection();
metadata.getFieldInformation().add(titleInfo);
metadata.getFieldInformation().add(contentTypeInfo);

// Copy the new file to the portal document list
Holder<Long> copyIntoResult = new Holder<Long>();
Holder<CopyResultCollection> result = new Holder<CopyResultCollection>();

client.copyIntoItems("http://null", destinationUrls, metadata, fileBytes, copyIntoResult, result);
```

But it's soo quirky. `destinationUrls.getString().add()`? And `Holder<Long>` as opposed to `Long`?

Comment: Can you put your full code here. I am trying exactly same and I am a little new to Java.
Thank you
Bobby

Comment: How to upload a large document to SharePoint from mobile device (where it is not enough RAM to store whole "fileBytes")? Is it possible to divide the fileBytes on parts?

Comment: Could you upload the full class? :( Would really appreciate it as it's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: how to copy folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have SPACE in Internal Name. Please see below the corrected content.

```
// Content type meta
FieldInformation contentTypeInfo = new FieldInformation();
contentTypeInfo.setDisplayName("Content Type");
contentTypeInfo.setInternalName("ContentType");
contentTypeInfo.setType(FieldType.CHOICE);
contentTypeInfo.setValue("Document");
```