# Uploading files to SharePoint 2013 via SOAP

Tags: sharepoint-online, soap

i am trying to upload image files(jpg, png, etc..) to SharePoint 2013 from an java applet via SOAP(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx), but i am alway getting the same exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.CopyIntoItemsResponse do not have a property of the name return
```

code:

public class SharePoint {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CopySoap temp = getPort("username", "password");
    CreateDocument(temp);
}

public static CopySoap getPort(String username,String password){
    Copy service = new Copy();
    CopySoap port = service.getCopySoap();

    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,username);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_vti_bin/copy.asmx");

    return port;
}

public static void CreateDocument(CopySoap port) throws IOException {
    String url = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SiteAssets/test.jpg";
    String sourceUrl = "http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/1c/c3/4e/1cc34e4e0aaeff76484b3ae963bfc701.jpg";//<-- for example

    DestinationUrlCollection urls = new DestinationUrlCollection();
    urls.getString().add(url);

    URL Iurl = new URL(sourceUrl);
    Image image = ImageIO.read(Iurl);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "jpg", baos);
    byte[] content = baos.toByteArray();

    FieldInformation titelInfo = new FieldInformation();
    titelInfo.setDisplayName("Titel");
    titelInfo.setType(FieldType.TEXT);
    titelInfo.setValue("test img");

    FieldInformationCollection infos = new FieldInformationCollection();
    infos.getFieldInformation().add(titelInfo);

    CopyResultCollection results = new CopyResultCollection();

    Holder<CopyResultCollection> resultHolder = new Holder<CopyResultCollection>(results);
    Holder<Long> longHolder = new Holder<Long>(new Long(-1));

    port.copyIntoItems(sourceUrl,urls,infos,content,longHolder,resultHolder);


}
```

}

I have already taken a look at this: [How can I upload a file to a Sharepoint Document Library through SOAP web services using Java?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-through-soap-web-servic)
, but it throws the same exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Solution can be found here:
In this article Joe Chandler explains exactly how to consume the SharePoint SOAP api through Java, if you can't get your code to work you maybe want to take a look at this.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078906/enterprise-java/java-tip-consuming-sharepoint-web-services-with-a-java-client.html