# How do I set document metadata after upload via web services?

Tags: document-library, content-type, web-services, item

I am reading through this post [Upload a file to SharePoint through the built-in web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services) where upload is done in WSS. I am using SP 2010. Is there a piece of code already posted here that will add an item (via .net interface) using foundation web-services where content type is "XYX" as the target library has about 8 CT associated with it. (with metadata, using hashtable). I would hate to re-invent the wheel if someone already went through this scenario. I forgot about what account to use (like a service account) or user authentication.

How do I add an item with metadata to library for a specific content type using webservices in SP2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to populate the `FieldInformation` array. Using the code from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-the-built-in-web-services), here is an example:

```
// Populated FieldInformation!
SharePoint2007CopyService.FieldInformation information = new 
    SharePoint2007CopyService.FieldInformation();
information.DisplayName = "Content Type";
information.InternalName = "ContentType";
information.Type = FieldType.Choice;
information.Value = "XYZ";

SharePoint2007CopyService.FieldInformation[] info = { information };
```

<sub>I typed this using the references below.. haven't tested yet. :)</sub>

See also:

- [How can I upload a file to a Sharepoint Document Library using Silverlight and client web-services?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/1837/2070)
- [How can I upload a file to a Sharepoint Document Library through
  SOAP web services using Java?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-through-soap-web-service)
- [How do you use the CopyIntoItems method of the SharePoint Copy web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987581/98933)
- [Sharepoint (MOSS): Creating Document Library Items / Uploading Files to a Document Library](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/sharepoint-moss-creating-document-library-items-uploading-files-to-a-document-library/)