# What Webservice allows you to upload documents to a library?

Tags: web-services, library

So i just started a project and i would like to use a `webservice` to access my SharePoint site and upload a document to a particular library. I've found the webservice to use with lists which is `lists.asmx` but i can't find if there's one for libraries.

So, can someone help me and give me the url if that web service exists?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload documents to a document library use the "copy.asmx" service instead of lists.asmx

Reference links below

[Copy webservice](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/how-can-i-upload-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-using-silverlight-and-c)

[Copy and Sp webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244977/any-way-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-through-webservice)

Comment: Cool thanks, downloaded it, now find out how to use it lol. Thanks for the info :)